# Show $(1+h)^n-1=h[1+(1+h)+(1+h)^2+..+(1+h)^{(n-1)}].$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Show $$(1+h)^n-1=h\left[1+(1+h)+(1+h)^2+\cdots+(1+h)^{n-1}\right].$$

I tried to expand $(1+h)^n-1$ using binomial expansion. But I'm still stuck.

Comment: Hint: geometric series.

Comment: Put $1+h=q$.{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}

Comment: Got it, Thank you

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

Let $(1+h)=r$ then we need to check

$$r^n-1=(r-1)(1+r^2+\ldots+r^{n-1})$$

Answer (score 3):

Rather than using binomial expansion, try carrying out an induction argument directly. Assuming the result is true for some $n$ (the base case is trivial), we have

\begin{align*}
(1 + h)^{n + 1} - 1 &= \big((1 + h)^n - 1 + 1\big)(1 + h) - 1 \\
&= \left(h \sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} (1+h)^k + 1\right)(1 + h) - 1 \\
&= h \sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} (1 + h)^{k + 1} + (1 + h) - 1 \\
&= h \sum_{k = 1}^n (1 + h)^k + h(1 + h)^0 \\
&= h \sum_{k = 0}^{n} (1 + h)^k
\end{align*}

as desired.

---

Alternatively, you can do this with the binomial expansion provided that you know some identities about the sums of binomial coefficients. In particular, try matching the exponent $h^k$ on each side; on the left, the coefficient is just $\binom{n}{k}$. On the right, it's a sum of binomial coefficients.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: Recall $$x^n-y^n = (x-y)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+x^{n-3}y^2+...+x^2y^{n-3}+xy^{n-2}+y^{n-1})$$

For $y = 1$, you get

$$x^n-1 = (x-1)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+x^{n-3}+...+x^2+x+1)$$

Can you apply that here?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:- Geometric series
   $$1+\,(1+h)+\,(1+h)^2....+\,(1+h)^{n-1}$$